# adding a column in csv created from data in previous column in Bash

Tags: bash

I am new to Bash scripting and am not even sure what function i should be using. I've tried to use sed and awk but am making a mess of it. I have the below csv file called input.csv

```sh
"2021-01-22 22:02:00",475673,485,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.308788,-4.421722,-99
"2021-01-22 22:03:00",475674,485,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.329033,-4.373959,-99
"2021-01-22 22:04:00",475675,485,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.320374,-4.359528,-99
"2021-01-22 22:05:00",475676,485,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.329685,-4.494766,-99
"2021-01-22 22:06:00",475677,485,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.343422,-4.650154,-99
```

I need to add 2 new additional columns to the end of each line containing the hr and the hr plus minute info from the 1st column.
My desired output would look like

```sh
"2021-01-22 22:02:00",475673,485,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.308788,-4.421722,-99,22,2202
"2021-01-22 22:03:00",475674,485,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.329033,-4.373959,-99,22,2203
"2021-01-22 22:04:00",475675,485,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.320374,-4.359528,-99,22,2204
"2021-01-22 22:05:00",475676,485,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.329685,-4.494766,-99,22,2205
"2021-01-22 22:06:00",475677,485,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.343422,-4.650154,-99,22,2206
```

any help here would be greatly appreciated.
demailyea

Comment: honestly I was not anywhere near getting it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU awk

```
awk -F, -v val="22" '{ tim=substr($1,13,5);gsub(":","",tim);print $0","val","tim }' file
```

Pass a variable val to awk and then extract the time from the first comma separated value. Further remove the ":" from the time (tim variable). Print the line followed by a comma, val, a comma and tim.